# How to get single post by one author?

Tags: posts, wp-query, author, get-posts

I just want to get the most latest posts by an author.  I am using get_posts at the moment but I notice it doesn't take an author argument, so how I can I specify my author?

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '1');
$posts=get_posts( $args );
foreach($posts as $post)
{                           
    setup_postdata($post);
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$args = array( 'author' => 1, 'numberposts' => 1 );` The author parameter isn't documented on the `get_posts()` codex page, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google reveals http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

Look at using `wp_query()` with author parameters and a limit of 1 post.

---

*Note to editors: don't complain about me putting a link instead of typing the answer. I realise is is normally needed in case the link disappears, but since it is a link to the codex, this website will disappear before that link stops working. Peace.*

Comment: `$args = array( 'author' => 1, 'numberposts' => 1 );` The author parameter isn't documented on the `get_posts()` codex page, but it does work.

Comment: @developdaly this worked.  Thank you.  DO you want to put this comment as an answer and I will mark it correct?

Comment: @developdaly please type that as an answer so I can complete this qustion